# Keep only second attribute from each line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, cut

I have a csv file with 4 attributes in each line, delimited by comma. I'm trying to come up with a `sed` command to keep only the second attribute from each line. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off with `cut`:

```
cut -d "," -f 2 file.txt
```

If you want to remove dupes, and you don't mind the order of the entries, simply do:

```
cut -d "," -f 2 file.txt | sort -u
```

And to extend to attrs 1 and to, simply use:

```
cut -d "," -f 1,2 file.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: this works, how do I extend it to attributes 1 and 2 from the csv?

Comment: What if the fields contain `,`? `1,10,21\n
2,"11,45",22\n
3,12,23\n
4,13,24`

Comment: @anishsane If the field had `,` he'd probably not point it as the delimiter, right?

Comment: If the field contain a `,`, entire field is enclosed in double quotes. See the file contents given in my previous comment. (sadly SO comments eat away newline characters...)

Comment: @anishsane If the field has what was being considered the delimiter, you must find another delimiter; i didn't get what is separating the fields in the example you passed. Why do you have "" enclosing only some numbers?

Comment: Ok... First, the content I gave were from a VALID csv file, created using Micro$oft excel -> save as csv. Try this: _In excel or openoffice calc, enter some random data, like I entered. In one of the cells, add a `,`. (User is allowed to put any data in the cells; it's the responsibility of the software, to handle it intelligently.) Then save it as .csv & open with a text editor_.

Comment: @anishsane yep, and handling intelligently here is using another delimiter to separate fields; the delimiter is simply **anything** that does not go in the field.

Comment: If you choose it as `comma separated values`, it will be forced to use `,` as delimiter... Hence it (read: office software) quotes the entire field in double quotes. Similarly, try to put a newline character in any cell (using office software). a `"` is escaped as `""` ;)

Comment: @anishsane oui, and what's the problem with it? it's simply granting none of the inner content to mess up the delimiter defined.

Comment: Yes, & that's where `cut` command would fail, since delimiter is contained in the field. For his particular case, it may work, because he does not have such case in his csv. I am only saying that simply `cut` is not robust enough solution. It however would serve the purpose here.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need sed for this . The fastest is with `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f2 file
```

However , if you want sed , you can do it so:

```
sed '/[^,]*,\([^,]*\).*/ sxx\1x' file
```